# High performance serialization and deserialization to cache objects in redis

Tags: java, serialization, redis, jackson

we are currently writing a REST service with `jax-rs` where we are caching the DB entities(`javax.persistence.Entity`) i.e.object representation of a table in database, in the redis server. Before even putting the objects to redis we serialize the objects to `json` via [`jackson`](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) and when we need the entity object we deserialize it after fetching from redis.

I want to know whether there is a **faster/more performant way** of doing serialization and deserialization. I am ok if somebody suggest a more performant way without converting the object to human readable format like json and also i don't want the intra language interoperability.

Please let me know if somebody needs some more details on this. Thanks.

Comment: I'm only slightly familiar with the libraries you're talking about but I think I understand the problem. In my mind, the question is do you always need the entity; will every entity you serialize be deserialized? If yes, then I think your solution is as good as it's going to get. If no, perhaps you could serialize the object using standard serialization and then perform the JSON transfer once you need to use it.

Comment: I'm also clueless regarding the above mentioned libraries, but consider using Redis' Hashes to store your entities. This will save you from the need of serialization/deserialization entirely.

Comment: @ItamarHaber But how will you store the object, you need to serialize it. right?

Comment: Not necessarily - the Hash data structure accommodates field->value mapping which is quite easily mapped to a table's row/JSON format. Once your object is stored in a Hash, you can access individual fields (for read/write) without going through expensive deserialization an reserialization of the entire corpus.

Comment: "*I want to know whether there is a faster/more performant way of doing serialization and deserialization.*" In order for someone to answer this you first need to tell us how fast/"performant" your current method is, as well as how much faster/more "performant" is acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

There are many, many libraries for serializing Objects in Java. [JVM Serializers](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers) benchmark, for example, includes two dozens or so.

Couple of things that do help you get even faster serialization, if that is the primary concern:

- If you use Jackson databind, check out [Afterburner](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-afterburner) module: it can speed up handling by 20-30% without any changes to code
- Try binary JSON formats like `Smile` or `CBOR` with Jackson (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-smile, https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-cbor). These are not developer-readable, but take up less space, are bit faster to process, and can be read from other languages too (i.e. not Java specific)
- If compatibility with JSON structure does not matter, and you do not need support from languages other than Java, [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) is relatively mature ser/deser library, used by many systems.

For JSON, Jackson is amongst fastest, and while there are some cases where others (Boon, fastjson) can be faster, you really need to benchmark your particular use case to know if yours is one. But even then, difference is unlikely to be huge.

Answer (score 1):

If you eventually need all your entities as JSON your approach is fine otherwise as Robert already pointed out <del>use default serialization</del>

according to those benchmarks, jackson is faster than java serialization:
[benchmark](https://github.com/RichardHightower/json-parsers-benchmark/wiki/Serialization-Jackson-vs.-Boon-vs.-Java-Serialization)

If you use jackson, only thing I recall is that the creation of the ObjectMapper is expensive.
[jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonBestPracticesPerformance)

To get the last bit out of it, you should mayber compare other json serializers/parsers with jackson, e.g. boon is quite fast. [boon](https://github.com/boonproject/boon/wiki/Boon-JSON)

Comment: are you telling that java default serialization is faster than jackson, if the singleton objectmapper is used.

Comment: i was but i am not sure anymore.

Comment: No, Java serialization is very inefficient for individual, relatively small objects. It works more efficiently (relatively speaking) for bigger graphs, as cause for overhead is that it has to serialize class metadata. For larger graphs that's less of an issue, as ratio of data to metadata grows.

Answer (score 1):

If you go for MessagePack you have support inside Redis Lua scripting, so you'll be able to do things like fetching a single field from Redis without transferring the whole object back to the client. However my Java knowledge is super limited so I've no idea if MessagePack is a viable serialization format for Java objects.